# Saving a document to SharePoint brings up "Web File Properties" dialog with incorrect metadata

Tags: sharepoint, moss, document, content-type

**Situation:**

- A custom "Master Document" content type inherits from Document
- The "Master Document" content type has five additional choice fields
- There are five custom "Document Template" content types that inherit from the "Master Document" content type
- Each of the "Document Template" content types uses a different Word document template (.dot) file
- Each of the "Document Template" content types have been added to a document library

**Problem:**

1. I click on a document in the library
2. Document opens up in Word 2003 for me to edit
3. I make some changes and save
4. A box pops up called "Web File Properties". The window contains all of my custom metadata properties and the ContentType field. The ContentType field is set correctly to the current content type. The other fields are reset to their default values. This same window can apparently be opened by going to File -> Properties

This window by itself would be fine except for two reasons:

- It includes the ContentType column
- All of my custom metadata properties are visible but are reset to their default values instead of whatever values were previously selected. This means, every time the user wants to save the document, they have to remember what properties were tagged and set them back.

**Question:**

1. Can I disable this Web File Properties box?
2. If no... can I get the fields that show up to be populated to their correct values?
3. If no... is there a way to disable my fields from displaying in this window?
4. If no... is this a SharePoint page that I can modify?

`***`***Edit with some more information***`***`

It looks like this only happens in Office 2003 and looks like it affects Choice fields. If I create the same column as a *Lookup* field, it seems to work.

*Edit again*

Looks like if the lookup field is a multi-select field then it will not show up in the Web File Properties box at all (single select lookups still work).

*edit 10/14/2009*

Link to the KB Article mentioned below by Brenda:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971500/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI - I want to CORRECT my previous post.  **The fix DID FIX my problem after I deleted my internet cache.**  Works PERFECT now.  Here is the KB you need:  KB971500  I can email you the fix if you can't find it.  The notes in the document do not describe the problem exactly as I would have, but it was the fix for my case.

bhartson@lbrealty.com

Comment: Awesome! Hopefully we can get this installed soon and then I will comment back here.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a workaround rather than an answer but I figured I might as well put it here in case it helps someone else.

It seems as if these issues with the Web File Properties box is specific to Office 2003. The issues I reported above seem to be fixed in Office 2007.

If you want to get it working in 2003 and you have choice/lookup fields in your **Document** content type, here is the summary:

- Single select Choice fields **DO NOT** work
- Multi select Choice fields DO work
- Single select Lookup fields DO work
- Multi select Lookup fields **DO NOT** work

Answer (score 0):

We have the EXACT problem.  I've opened a case with Microsoft back in February and they were able to finally duplicate my problem.

I have been kept informed and told that my fix would be available with the JUNE cumulative upates.  I just received a specific hotfix from my Microsoft rep and applied it and it still did NOT fix my problem.  I am hoping he gave me the wrong one and has the real one to send me.

Thanks for your post.  I'm may try some of your suggestions above but I just want Microsoft to fix this.  We can't upgrade to Office2007!

Thanks.

Comment: We are in the same situation (may eventually upgrade to 2007, but who knows when). Hopefully some of my info is helpful to you and thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

man, this was really killing me, I spent an entire day recreating document libraries and all sorts of content-types and variations of my excel template before I figured this was a bug... At least MS has a little hotfix request thing now... they're going to send it to me I guess :\

I didn't test this in excel/office 2003 and really botched a presentation of our little workflow... embarassing... always test with the app & environment people are going to use!!!

thanks for the KB article number